# How to implement IWindowCloseHandler in Eclipse (e4) RCP?

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp, e4, messagedialog

How can I implement **IWindowCloseHandler** in order to display a **MessageDialog** before closing the application  ?

Here is my code :

**EDIT**

```
public class LifeCycle {    

 @PostContextCreate
 public void postContextCreate()
  {
    // TODO start up code here

     System.out.println("open");

  }

 @ProcessAdditions
  void processAdditions(MApplication app, EModelService modelService)
  {
     WindowCloseHandler closeHandler=new WindowCloseHandler();
    MWindow window = (MWindow)modelService.find("uploadcenter.source.trimmedwindow.0", app);
    window.getContext().set(IWindowCloseHandler.class, closeHandler);
  }
 private static class WindowCloseHandler implements IWindowCloseHandler{

    @Override
    public boolean close(MWindow window) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Shell shell = new Shell();

        if (MessageDialog.openConfirm(shell, "Confirmation",
                "Do you want to exit?")) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    } 
 }
```

}

Ismail

Comment: If this is a pure e4 application you can't use PlatformUI.

Comment: Okay @greg-449, I can understand better e4 RCP app now. So , in my latest edit, I'm using `EModelService` and `MApplication` to find the main window of my app and I got my window in `processAddictions()`. The LifeCycle class is in the `plugin.xml`. Now , I just need to pass the window to the `close` method, but I can't, what am I missing to do this last step ?

Comment: As I already said you put the `IWindowCloseHandler` in the window context and Eclipse will call the `close` method when it is needed. You must wait until the app startup event fires to put the entry in the context. I have updated the answer to match your code

Comment: I couldn't see yout updates (sorry), I was editing at the same time I guess. I've added new modification too . . . I'm getting `NullPointerException` here  : `window.getContext().set(IWindowCloseHandler.class, closeHandler);`. Does my new edits correct ? Why I'm getting `NullPointerException` ? . Sorry again for not seeing your edits

Comment: The context is not yet set up when `@ProcessAdditions` is called, you **must** do this in the app startup complete event as I have shown.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `IWindowCloseHandler` must be registered in the Eclipse context (`IEclipseContext`) for the `MWindow` which you want to control.

```
MWindow window = get the window

window.getContext().set(IWindowCloseHandler.class, handler);
```

If you want to set this up in the `LifeCycle` class there is a bit of work to do because the life cycle methods are called too early in the application start up to be able to set the value in the context directly. It is necessary to wait for the app startup complete event:

```
public class LifeCycle
{
  @ProcessAdditions
  public void processAdditions(IEventBroker eventBroker, MApplication app, EModelService modelService)
  {
     MWindow window =(MWindow)modelService.find("uploadcenter.source.trimmedwindow.0", app);

     eventBroker.subscribe(UIEvents.UILifeCycle.APP_STARTUP_COMPLETE, 
                          new AppStartupCompleteEventHandler(window));
  }


  private static class AppStartupCompleteEventHandler implements EventHandler
  {
    private MWindow theWindow;

    AppStartupCompleteEventHandler(MWindow window)
    {
       theWindow = window;
    }


    @Override
    public void handleEvent(final Event event)
    {
      theWindow.getContext().set(IWindowCloseHandler.class, handler);        
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I want to control the main window. So to get it  , i did : `MWindow window= (MWindow) PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getShell();`. And now, `LifeCycle` class is a normal class (not anymore in the `plugin.xml`. Now , I can't `getContext` ! . Please, see my edit .

Comment: You `LifeCycle` must still be declared in the plugin.xml as the life cycle class. You can't use PlatformUI, you must find the window using `EModelService`.

Comment: I can't use `IEventBroker` and no import is suggested, same for `EventHandler`

Comment: `IEventBroker` is in the `org.eclipse.e4.core.services` plugin

Comment: `EventHandler` is in `org.eclipse.osgi.services`

Comment: Thank you @greg-449 , it's working now. I'm finally getting the `MessageDialog`. Your indications were very important in both questions I've posted to find the solution.

Answer (score 1):

A variation on @greg-449's answer using dependency injection and annotation. Register this class as an addon in your Application.e4xmi.

```
public class ExampleWindowCloseAddon implements IWindowCloseHandler
{
    @Inject
    @Optional
    public void startupComplete(@UIEventTopic(UIEvents.UILifeCycle.APP_STARTUP_COMPLETE) MApplication application,
            EModelService modelService)
    {
        MWindow window = (MWindow) modelService.find("my.window.id", application);
        window.getContext().set(IWindowCloseHandler.class, this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean close(MWindow window)
    {
        // Your code goes here
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried this, but `window.getContext().set(...)` crashed because `getContext()` returned null. Any ideas what might be the problem? I am using the Eclipse Kepler release 4.3.1.

Comment: @skowski are you sure your window.id exists.